# Radix Sort in Python

Tags: python, function, radix-sort

I could use some help. How would you write a program in python that implements a radix sort?

Here is some info:

> A radix sort for base 10 integers is a based on sorting punch cards,
>   but it turns out the sort is very ecient. The sort utilizes a main
>   bin and 10 digit bins. Each bin acts like a queue and maintains its
>   values in the order they arrive. The algorithm begins by placing each
>   number in the main bin. Then it considers the ones digit for each
>   value. The rst value is removed and placed in the digit bin
>   corresponding to the ones digit. For example, 534 is placed in digit
>   bin 4 and 662 is placed in the digit bin 2. Once all the values in the
>   main bin are placed in the corresponding digit bin for ones, the
>   values are collected from bin 0 to bin 9 (in that order) and placed
>   back in the main bin. The process continues with the tens digit, the
>   hundreds, and so on. After the last digit is processed, the main bin
>   contains the values in order. Use randint, found in random, to create
>   random integers from 1 to 100000. Use a list comphrension to create a
>   list of varying sizes (10, 100, 1000, 10000, etc.). To use indexing to
>   access the digits rst convert the integer to a string. For this sort
>   to work, all numbers must have the same number of digits. To zero pad
>   integers with leading zeros, use the string method str.zfill(). Once
>   main bin is sorted, convert the strings back to integers.

I'm not sure how to start this, Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thought SO is willing to help, we cannot give you the code. To start off, write a pseudo code, and then convert it to Python code. If you are stuck somewhere, Post your code here, and you are more likely to get a better response.

Answer (score 6):

Type the following text into your browser:

```
www.google.com
```

Hit enter. Now, type the following text into the wide text box:

```
python radix sort example
```

Hit enter again. Among the results you will find [this](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/python/sorting/radixsort) one. You can use it as a model, study it and when you feel you are able to implement it yourself, implement it. Cheers!